# Javascript: How to access an array object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

i'm trying to access to an array object, but i just receive a "undefined" message on my console, i tried several ways of this forum, but no one helped me, please show me how to access it[image]

Comment: Like, `var arrObjs = [{'administrator_id': 3}, {'administrator_id': 4}]; var firstAdministratorId = arrObjs[0].administrator_id`

Comment: The screenshots shows that the array is empty when you log it. It smells like an asynchronicity problem.

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: There is about a 90% chance you logged the array to the console at a point in time when it was not yet populated (for example, immediately after invoking an asynchronous call, but before it finished). Then, when you opened up the array in the console by pressing on the little black arrow, the data had now been retrieved, so it is displayed. Make sure you don't try to access the array before the asynchronous call finished. In other words, access it only in the `then` or `subscribe` handler or callback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is no clear which array you want to access. In javascript it is simple to access array with Index like `nameOfarray[Index].property_name`.

```
var user=[
  {'name':'abc',id:1,'subject':[{'math':90,'english':80}]},
  {'name':'abc1',id:2,'subject':[{'math':90,'english':80}]},
  {'name':'abc2',id:3,'subject':[{'math':90,'english':80}]}
];
```

val name=user[0].name;
var math_mark=user[0].subject[0].math;

Answer (score 0):

What you have here is basically an array of objects.

Let's say `arrayobj` represents your variable that contains this whole thing that you've done a console.log of, so to access, say, `picturepath` of the first object (which has index 0 in the array), you can write -

```
arrayobj[0].picturepath
```

Similarly, by changing the index (of the array), you can get to the next object and to access object elements, you have to use `.elementindex`

So in general -

`array[arrayindex].objectindex` should give you the required results.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to do operations on an object that is printed to the chrome console, right click on the object and do `Store as global variable`. Then you can access it using the name `temp1` or whatever is printed out in the console.

Answer (score -1):

You can access array values by entering index of theme.

for example `array[0].administrators_id` return `3`

if you love firefox , you can use firefox.
in Firefox console by click on array you can see it's content on right side.

[image: Firefox Console Show Array]