# I want to print the given JSON data into an HTML. I want to print the "articles" array from the given JSON data. This is for Postman Visualizer part

Tags: javascript, html, json, postman

Below is the JSON data ;

I want to print the articles array bifurcated according the the variables given like:

Author :  Davide Urietti
and so on.....

```
 {
    "status": "ok",
    "totalResults": 12099,
    "articles": [
        {
            "source": {
                "id": null,
                "name": "Corriere.it"
            },
            "author": "Davide Urietti",
            "title": "Tesla, disponibile il Full Self Driving con un abbonamento mensile",
            "description": "Pagando 199 euro al mese, i possessori di una Tesla potranno sfruttare le funzionalità della guida autonoma. In precedenza, invece, il Full Self Driving (10.000 dollari) andava richiesto in fase di acquisto del veicolo.",
            "url": "https://www.corriere.it/tecnologia/21_luglio_23/tesla-disponibile-full-self-driving-un-abbonamento-mensile-0c829864-e871-11eb-a441-7c7ca8688e2a.shtml",
            "urlToImage": "https://images2.corriereobjects.it/methode_image/socialshare/2021/07/19/59b399b6-eb88-11eb-8dfd-2426b1e21c4f.jpg",
            "publishedAt": "2021-07-23T07:35:30Z",
            "content": "di Davide Urietti Pagando 199 euro al mese, i possessori di una Tesla potranno sfruttare le funzionalità della guida autonoma. In precedenza, invece, il Full Self Driving (10.000 dollari) andava rich… [+1592 chars]"
        },
    // similarly there are more rows like these
      ]
    }
```

Below is the HTML Code I tried :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Convert a string into a date object.</h2>

<p id="demo"></p>


<script>
const obj = JSON.parse(articles);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = obj.author + ", " + obj.title; 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `author` isn't defined on `obj`, but it is a property of an item in the `articles` array

Comment: @evolutionxbox How can I define author as an obj and print the required data

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript: How to access an array object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39177519/javascript-how-to-access-an-array-object)

Comment: @evolutionxbox Yeah, thanks